# how to configure routing from internal machine to internet via another machine?

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have an internal machine , say X (not connected to internet)  that is connected to a machine, say Y which is connected to the internet .

How should I configure the machines to be able to route from internal machine X to internet through Y?

Comment: what OS ? tagged "iptables", so one can assume linux, but want to be sure...

Comment: Ah and maybe X isn't connected to the internet for security reasons. It could be a bad idea to route on Y...

Comment: @petrus: If it should be secure, than dual-homing of Y just made all your security go with the drain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default router **Y** uses must know that the network **X** uses is available through **Y**.

so, if **X** is at 192.168.1.12/24, **Y** is at 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.0.101/24. Then at the router (let's say at 192.168.0.1/24, connected to Internet) that shares connection with **Y** you need to add:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.101 scope global
```

and appropriate rules to firewall to let traffic through.

The other solution is to use SNAT in **Y**:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(assuming that the network between **Y** and **Y**'s default router is connected to eth0)

In both cases you need to add packet forwarding to **Y**:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: +1. I'd say that SNAT is the way to go.

Comment: MASQUERADE isn't actually SNAT and is in fact inferior to SNAT.

In simple terms; if your WAN IP is dynamically assigned, you should use MASQUERADE, if not, use SNAT.

Why? because if the physical connection goes down, MASQUERADE causes all connections to be forgotten, SNAT doesn't.

Comment: @Olipro: MASQUERADE both is and isn't SNAT, SNAT is far more flexible, at the same time requires explicit configuration. If your external IP changes then using MASQUERADE will save you at least a few headaches. Everything depends on the specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

Set the gateway on machine X as Y. Then make sure host Y allows packet-forwarding. On linux with iptables this would require more or less this:

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to allow forwarding, make sure `net.ipv4.ip_forward` has been set to `1`.

After that, apply a rule in iptables to allow the traffic.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(if eth0 is the right device)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

On machine X, set the default route to be Y.

If that works, permanently set it by adding

> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

to: /etc/sysctl.conf

and restarting.

Comment: I'm assuming that Y is behind a router, you haven't actually said that.  Or is Y a firewall ?